# Oracle Pro*C ORA-12547

Tags: oracle, tns, oracle-pro-c

I'm working on re-compiling some Pro*C code that no one currently at my company has ever compiled. It's compiling OK, but when I copy it to the production server and run it I'm getting Oracle error ORA-12547 (TNS: lost contact)

Any ideas?

Comment: See [**How to resolve ORA-12547: TNS :lost contact when try to connect to Oracle**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/11/03/ora-12547-tns-lost-contact-when-try-to-connect-to-oracle/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, figured it out. :-)

The C executable isn't run directly on the server, but launched through a script that sets up the connection environment. i.e. something like this:

```
export SHLIB_PATH=/oracleDatabaseSidHere/oracle/10.2/lib:/usr/lib:/oracleDatabaseSidHere/oracle/10.2/odg/lib
export ORACLE_BASE=/oracleDatabaseSidHere/oracle
export ORACLE_SID=oracleDatabaseSidHere
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracleDatabaseSidHere/oracle/10.2

# Set up the path and executable to run
PATH=.\:$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usrlocal/bin
PATH=$PATH:/path_to_application_logs

cd /path_to_application
application
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to this, I just found out that I get the same error ORA-12547 TNS lost contact on my Windows machine when I try to connect to an Oracle database with PL/SQL and at the same time I have a VPN connection open.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Linux, Oracle 11gR2. Oracle owner could run SQL*Plus and get in via either TNS or local connection. Non-oracle user could log in via TNS, but not as local connection.

Turns out the answer was that the ORACLE_HOME filesystem was mounted "nosuid". Removing that mount option solved my issue.